# Magnifier SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to render 2 SwiftUI views, in a `VStack`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let content = // [...]
    let magnifier = // [...]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            self.content
            self.magnifier
        }
    }
}
```

The first view (i.e., `content`) is a `TextView`, the second view (i.e., `magnifier`) is just a magnifier to the first view with a given scale and offset. This is basically the "zoom" functionality of some notes apps, Notability for example.

With UIKit I would have write a class `Magnifier: UIView`, and in its `draw()` function, something like

```swift
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    // [...]
    self.contentView.layer.render(in: context)
}
```

Can we do something like that with SwiftUI or do we have to use UIKit and `UIViewRepresentable`?

Comment: You can investigate https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-magnification-gesture-fa41b9bd404e plus MagnificationGesture, may help you for images

Comment: I  think the problem with this is that you have only 1 view: the Image. In my case I want a view to be render at two distinct places: in `content`, and in `magnifier` with a scale.

Comment: I would use a ZStack, with one view at 1.0, scale, and repeat the same view at X scale (magnified).  Then use a SwiftUI mask (animated) to follow the screen touches and reveal the scaled overlay as needed.